# How to prove this trigonometric inequality

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, proof-writing

$$ \sin\left(\frac{2x_1 +x_2 +x_3}{4}\right)>\frac{2\sin(x_1) +\sin(x_2) +\sin(x_3)}{4} ; 0<x_1 <x_2 <x_3 <\pi $$

How to prove the above inequality?

Comment: @Arnaldo - I am unable to take a start. Actually I have solved a similar question: $ \sin [(a+b+c)/3] > (a+b+c)/3 ; 0<a<b<c< \pi $

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, since $\sin(x) < x$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$.

Comment: This does not look true to me. If x are large, then $2x_1+x_2 + x_3$ could be larger than $4$

Comment: @YujieZha - I have made the correction

Comment: @Marc - I have edited the question.

Comment: It is still not true, since you can make the argument of sine as close to $0$ as you want, and $\sin(a)<a$ for small $a$.

Comment: @MrigankShekharPathak Your edit does not make it correct.Take x1=1, x2=1.1, x3=1.2

Comment: @mickep - Please have a look at the question again.

Comment: @YujieZha - I am sorry for the mistake, i have edited the question

Comment: Now it is true because $\sin x$ is concave at $(0,\pi)$. You can use Jensen Inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Regards @Mrigank.

May i give you partial detail. I would first write an equation

$$ f(x,y,z) = \sin \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{4} + \frac{z}{4} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin(x) -\frac{1}{4} \sin(y) - \frac{1}{4} \sin(z)$$

Then notice that $f(0,0,0) =  0$. Now lets look at the partial derivatives below :

\begin{align*} F(x,y,z) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \\ &= \cos \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{4} + \frac{z}{4} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(x) -\frac{1}{4} \cos(y) - \frac{1}{4} \cos(z) \end{align*}

You should prove that the derivatives are positive in some interval. Since $\cos(u)$ is decreasing when $0 < u < \pi$, we get that when $0<x<y<z<\pi$ :

$$\cos \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{4} + \frac{z}{4} \right) > 0.5 \cos(z)$$
Next we also need to have
$$\cos \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{4} + \frac{z}{4} \right) >  \cos(x) + 0.5 \cos(y)$$
In order to get
$$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{4} + \frac{z}{4} \right) > \cos(x) + 0.5\cos(y) + 0.5 \cos(z) $$
This means $F(x,y,z)>0$, or $f$ is increasing. This should prove the relation considered. 
Thanks.